Ubuntu installer (20, 22, or 24) won't boot on Dell inspiron 3891
I can't get the Ubuntu installer booted on this Dell Inspiron 3891 - it gets as far as GRUB, but hangs (black screen) on "Try or Install" and also "Safe Graphics" chosen from the GRUB menu.  I've disabled Secure Boot and TPM support, but nothing has changed.
The really annoying thing is, Debian 12 installed just fine - but I need Ubuntu for this system because of some vendor support issues.  EDIT: Debian 12 did, in fact, install "just fine" - but when I go to boot from the installation, a very similar thing happens: it loads the initrd, then hangs on the graphical GRUB screen, apparently crashed. However, if I boot the alternate kernel (6.1.0-18, instead of 6.1.0-20), it fully boots!
What can I do to get the installer booted, or failing that, is there a way I can drop Ubuntu 22.04 (the particular version I was targeting) over top of this Debian install?  (Specifically - can I launch the Ubuntu installer directly from Debian?  I don't need to keep the Debian install at this point, but I can't even get the Ubuntu installer booted)
UPDATE: After banging my head against this most of the day, I ran across a BIOS update (I had looked yesterday, but the only one I could find was the version I'm already running).  Updating the BIOS of the Inspiron 3891 from version 1.5 to version 1.24 (which apparently was released two weeks ago) has allowed the machine to boot the Ubuntu 22 installer (finally!)
Thanks to all who tried helping.

"of some vendor support issues." says who?! debian and ubuntu hardware stack are the same and changes between them are not affecting us users.  " is there a way I can drop Ubuntu 22.04 over top of this Debian i (nstall?" yes... but it is not the  best method. purge the desktop, drop to a terminal session (tty1), change the sources to Ubuntu, update, upgrade and install a desktop. MIND that this will probably bork your system if debian versions are newer.(deleting the debian desktop prior removes a lot of those issues ;))

I would first check if your installer was OK. Does it have to be Ubuntu (Gnome 3 version)? Can it be Cinnamon or Budgie? If you install those you can put the gnome3 desktop witth it (and choose it from login). That will make the system fully Ubuntu.

@Rinzwind not sure what you mean by "check if installer was OK" - I've made 3 different bootable USB thumb drives (ubuntu 20.04, 22.04, and 24.04) and all three exhibit the same behavior - the black screen well before the installer comes up.  The 22.04 installer I have actually used to install on a different system without problems.

Have you tried any other kernel options?

Does this answer your question? Is there a program to install Ubuntu from a Linux system?

@eyoung100 - the "nomodeset" option in that post is what is set by the "Safe Graphics" option in the GRUB menu of newer Ubuntu (the post says "starting in 19", and I've tried 20, 22, and 24) - and it didn't help.  I DO agree that a kernel option would probably do it - but WHAT kernel option?  And why might Debian 12 work with one kernel but not the default (ie, 6.1.0-20 doesn't work, but 6.1.0-18 does).  I'd love more suggestions!

@karel - maybe?  It's not written to provide actual info on "here's what's needed to install Ubuntu", so it relies on the user (aka, me) having a lot more information about what constitutes "Ubuntu" vs. "Debian" than I actually do.  If there was something (in that answer, or another) which either provided a comprehensive "here are the differences" or "here's an actual command line to pass to debootstrap", it might help, but as it is, it does a bunch to convince me "yes, it may be technically possible, but no, not worth actually attempting"

@riz94107 Did you try one of the other options?  I linked that post because all the options are available in the picture in Karel's answer

@eyoung100 I tried the ones that made any sense (some are for older kernels, and no longer relevant).  The best I've been able to do so far is to set gfxmode=text, and then I get to see that it always (with all sets of options I've tried) hangs after a message that says
EFI stub: Loaded initrd from LINUX_EFI_INITRD_MEDIA_GUID device path

Let's see if this is just a Ubuntu issue or happens with all live CD's/USB's....Create a Fedora 40 Workstation and an Arch Installer from a mirror.  These are both distributions that aren't descendants of Debian, but if they fail in the same way we'll have narrowed the issue down to a computer setting.

@eyoung100 Sorry, after my last response to you but before yours, I edited the question to reflect that I'd found a new BIOS update (less than two weeks old) which seems to have fixed the problem I was having and I was able to successfully install (and now run) Ubuntu 22.  (Previous searches for BIOS updates had somehow only turned up older updates which I'd already applied)  Thank you (sincerely) for your attempts to help.

I'm adding this here for future readers: Dell BIOS and UEFI Updates
